# Closing prettyPhoto onclick

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I cant figure out how to simply close a prettyPhoto.

I use following code to open a dynamic instance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.prettyPhoto();
    $.prettyPhoto.open('<?php echo $path; ?>/news/<?php echo $get_hot_news[img]; ?>');
});
```

There is by default a close button in bottom right corner and the prettyPhoto frame closes if you click outside of it but not all people figure that out, thats why I need to close it upon cliking anywhere inside the prettyPhoto itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about closing when the user clicks anywhere in the body of the page?

```
$('body').on('click',function() {
    $.prettyPhoto.close();
});
```

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.4.4 its quite an old project so it may not have on() function declared yet, however it works with click() function instead of on() which I call for $(document) object. That works for me well. Thank you for pointing me in this direction.